# Confused as to how this map[string]struct is defined

Tags: go

I understand maps in go, but this code snippet confuses me:

```
testCases := map[string]struct {
        pod      *api.Pod
        required []corev1.ResourceName
        err      string
    }{
        "init container resource missing": {
            pod: &api.Pod{
                Spec: api.PodSpec{
                    InitContainers: []api.Container{{
                        Resources: api.ResourceRequirements{
                            Requests: api.ResourceList{api.ResourceCPU: resource.MustParse("1m")},
                            Limits:   api.ResourceList{api.ResourceCPU: resource.MustParse("2m")},
                        },
                    }},
                },
            },
            required: []corev1.ResourceName{corev1.ResourceMemory},
            err:      `must specify memory`,
        },
        "container resource missing": {
            pod: &api.Pod{
                Spec: api.PodSpec{
                    Containers: []api.Container{{
                        Resources: api.ResourceRequirements{
                            Requests: api.ResourceList{api.ResourceCPU: resource.MustParse("1m")},
                            Limits:   api.ResourceList{api.ResourceCPU: resource.MustParse("2m")},
                        },
                    }},
                },
            },
            required: []corev1.ResourceName{corev1.ResourceMemory},
            err:      `must specify memory`,
        },
    }
```

I understand this:

```
testCases := map[string]struct
```

But what follows makes no sense to me.  How does the code go own to define an api.Pod, corev1.ResourceName etc.?
That is not a string to struct definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`testCases` is a map with keys of type `string` and values of the anonymous type:

```
struct {
    pod      *api.Pod
    required []corev1.ResourceName
    err      string
}
```

The `pod` is a pointer to a value of type `api.Pod` (also a struct), `required` is a slice with elements of type `corev1.ResourceName`, and `err` is a string.

So the `testCases` map will contain many strings that point to structs with the above structure.

Comment: ah, ok that makes sense now.  Thanks I was getting frustrated for a bit!

Answer (score 4):

What comes after is sort of a "anonymous" struct.

It will be the equivalent to :

```
testCases := map[string]StructName
```

If you had specified the struct like:

```
type StructName struct {
    pod      *api.Pod
    required []corev1.ResourceName
    err      string
}
```